# Adding Google Analytics to PHP Website

Tags: php, google-analytics

I'm new to Google Analytics and am trying to add it to my existing PHP website.  At this stage I only have access to the Content Management System which is used for creating new pages and inserting content.  As far as I am aware the page already has a Classic Analytics code (ga.js) which was put there by the company who created the website.

According to the following page from Google I should be able to add a Universal Analytics tracking code (analytics.js) to my content and it should work harmoniously.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032400?hl=en

I've gone ahead and added the tracking code at the end of my content for each of the pages on the site.

Unfortunately I don't think the pages views are being shown accurately when I log in and look at the stats.  They are being displayed as follows:

[image]

Where are all the other pages?  Why aren't they coming up on the list?  Am I making a beginners mistake?

To make this easier for you to see what I'm talking about, the site I'm working on is [This Site](http://www.maryborougheducationcentre.vic.edu.au).

**UPDATE:**

I've added the Google Analytics Debug add on for Chrome.  It seems to be showing the same error on each page I go to in the browser.  Here's an example:

http://www.maryborougheducationcentre.vic.edu.au/community.php?id=66

**Error:**
community.php?
id=66:484
Uncaught SyntaxError:
Unexpected Identifier

**UPDATE:**

Unfortunately I had forgotten that the Content Management System on the website uses square brackets to know where to insert html code for images.  What a pain.  This is what caused the two different looking tracking codes as you can see in the answer below.  Anyway, at least I know what was causing problem.  Thanks again Sina!

Comment: followed the tips here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008083?hl=en

Comment: FWIW, you should not have both ga.js and analytics.js on the same page. If you do, you'll get double counts for everything.

Comment: @PhilipWalton The page I referenced above says that it should be ok?  The two tracking codes are for different google accounts?

Comment: @PaulMatthews sorry, I was just going to edit my comment to add that it's OK only if you're sending the hits to two different properties. If you send them to the same property you'll get double hits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you having 2 different codes in different pages?

For example, in index.php (working) you have:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-66181918-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Whereas in your `/studentservices.php?id=47` (not working) you have:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i<img style='padding:8px;' src=./images/services/'GoogleAnalyticsObject' align=right>=r;i<img style='padding:8px;' src=./images/services/r align=right>=i<img style='padding:8px;' src=./images/services/r align=right>||function(){
  (i<img style='padding:8px;' src=./images/services/r align=right>.q=i<img style='padding:8px;' src=./images/services/r align=right>.q||<img style='padding:8px;' src=./images/services/ align=right>).push(arguments)},i<img style='padding:8px;' src=./images/services/r align=right>.l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)<img style='padding:8px;' src=./images/services/0 align=right>;a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-66181918-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

You see the difference?

Comment: Yes I see the difference.  As I explained in my question the first one was put there by the company that created the website.  The second one was put there by me.  They are for 2 different google accounts.  Why is the second one "not working"?

Comment: I understand, but they are both sending data to **UA-66181918-1**, which is the same account. How is that happening?

Comment: @PaulMatthews mate, the code above (first one!) looks right according to the example snippet we have in google [tracking guides](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced?hl=en) page. Is there a way for you to modify the 2nd one? Or is that controlled by the company that created the website?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand.  When I load any page there is a tracking code in the `<head>` which references **UA-2419955-1**.  Then further down in the `<body>` there is another tracking code which references **UA-66181918-1**.  What am I missing?

Comment: Which one is yours mate? Can you go to your GA dashboard and check which tracking ID is yours?

Comment: Mine is **UA-66181918-1**.

Comment: Are you using the same code (the first one), for every page?

Comment: Do you mean the code changes from the first snippet in my answer, to the second snippet, just by itself? You must insert the first snippet in my answer, as for every page, because that is the one working. And the snippet done by the company (ending with 955-1), don't be concerned about it as it looks like it's working correctly in every page.

Comment: The **first** tracking code is generated by default by the server for each page.  I have to manually add the **second** tracking code by hand in each page I create.  I only have access to the content portion of any page.  That is the only place I can insert the code.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Ok we need to get this right mate. Do you mean **first** =UA-2419955-1 and **second** =UA-66181918-1. Or by **first** you mean the first snippet in my answer, and **second** accordingly the next one? Apologies mate :(

Comment: I don't know where you got the first and second snippets from in your answer.  That doesn't look right to me.  First =UA-2419955-1 and second =UA-66181918-1.  That's the way it reads if you look at the source in the browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87441/discussion-between-sina-and-paul-matthews).